# EPD Python vs System Python--OSX Mountain Lion 10.8

Tags: osx-mountain-lion, pycuda, enthought

I'm a two week old mac user, so bear with me here. I'm trying to set EPD python up as my default python interpreter instead of the system python that came with the mac. It was my understanding that EPD does this automatically upon installation by modifying the .bash_profile, but after I installed EPD, the .bash_profile was unaltered and as far as I can see, system python is still the default interpreter. How do I go about changing this?

The major reason why I want to change the default python to EPD is that all the packages I install are automatically placed into the /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages directory instead of the site-packages directory associated with EPD. In particular, I can't get PyCuda to install in EPD's site-packages directory.

I hope this made some sort of sense. I'm lost and not sure where to go from here. Help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I just use `brew install python` or `brew install python3`  and then `pythonX -m pip install package` you can try `brew install pyenv`

Answer (score 1):

Adding the line

`export PATH=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin:$PATH`

to your `.bashrc` file should work.

In theory the EPD installer should have done this job... maybe an issue with permissions?

Answer (score 0):

A few additional points.

Normally the EPD installer makes the PATH changes by adding lines to the bottom of ~/.bash_profile ; if you are sure that it did not, you can also check ~/.profile .

Perhaps you installed EPD as a different user?

Since you say that you are new to Mac, I'll also mention that the PATH would not have been changed in any terminal windows that had already been opened before you installed EPD.

Also, a crucial warning: since you've already installed 3rd-party packages into your system Python, please see this article:
https://support.enthought.com/entries/22094157-OS-X-Conflict-with-installed-packages-in-earlier-Python-installation

You may also find other useful articles in that same Knowledge Base site.